# SwiftyJson go through several arrays without cycles

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

How I can go through one array to next array without cycles?

JSON: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34BtT.png

I try to do like this

```
guard let items = self.json["data"]["reels_media"][]["items"].arrayValue else { return }
```

But I didn't receive items.

If I do like this:

```
guard let items = self.json["data"]["reels_media"][0]["items"].arrayValue else { return }
```

I didn't receive all elements of array.

Comment: what the problem with `["reels_media"][0]["items"]` ?? what elements are missing ?

Comment: for example in array 10 elements, but when I print this constant I received only 2-3 elements

Comment: `reels_media`  contains more than 1 item ?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. [Images of code are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste the code into your question.

Comment: You should probably start by representing `Media` and its `Items` by separate objects. Then you can parse them using recursion. Nowadays you should use `Decodable` instead `SwiftyJSON` anyway.

Comment: @Sh_Khan - yes, 2-3 elements

Comment: @anothermh - Ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let allItems = self.json["data"]["reels_media"].arrayValue.map({$0["items"].arrayValue}).joined()
print(allItems)
```

Comment: Very Great. Thank U